# birt, doc report and a very big file

Tags: java, birt, filesize, doc

We are using Birt to generate some reports in doc and pdf. Reports are simple, without any graphs and graphics. Only text.

My main problem is difference in the sizes of those files, for example:

- PDF - 251 KB, DOC - 5 584 KB
- PDF - 3 217 KB, DOC - 82 572 KB

We are not using any specific configuration for output file (only format: doc/pdf).

Is there any way to reduce the doc file size ?

thx 
Lukasz

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. This seems to be a reasonably clear description of the problem, one that falls within the scope of SO as described in http://stackoverflow.com/faq .

Comment: can you give us any indication of why you (or your users) need to export specifically to DOC format? For plain text, it's a notoriously "bloaty" format (ie. prone to being disproportionately large, in relation to its content).

Comment: Actually DOC (and PDF) is something we have to have, it is in the specification of our project. Our application presents information about companies, identification per KRS, way it was created, etc. Entire data is mainly text, nothing fancy, how ever as you noticed before, the amount of it is overwhelming.

Comment: Hello tzim.  Those are pretty large docs - 82Mb!? Is it reasonable though?  Do you have thousands of pages and lots of styling information?  I've see RTF with images go off the rails but generally not text only DOC format.

Comment: Hi jowierun. to be honest it got me by surprised too. Those page are about x00 pages, with lots of styling information. From what I noticed it, is around 70 lines styles for a 5 lines of text. So, just BIG WOW. Fortunately, we will be fixing this in a month or so, I will try to keep you all up to date :) wish us luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer would be to use a different output format instead of Word .doc - for example, html or xls. Alternatively, for really compact output, you could use the Export Data option from the report viewer to produce output in character-separated format (comma-separated, by default).

Alternatively, you could consider using custom BIRT emitters. There's a post on the subject on the BIRT World blog [here](http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2011/07/replacing-default-birt-xls-emitter.html) (specifically relating to xls emitters, although the Tribix emitters mentioned should also enable output to RTF, a Microsoft format readable by Word that is much more concise than doc).